# User profile link on help center page uses http instead of https

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, ssl, minimal-reproducible-example

I suppose all links to the Stack Exchange Network should be in HTTPS. Obviously this one in the [MCVE help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) was forgotten.

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>Click to see full image</sub>

Looks like this user specifically likes HTTP :)

Comment: @Liam The last sentence is just for fun. I intended to point out that this link should have been HTTPS.

Comment: @Liam click the image to enlarge. It's fairly obvious then

Comment: I'm trying to clarify your question. As it's written IMO it's not clear what exactly your going on about. But fine, whatever

Comment: If you click the link you'll end up in the https version of it. That's the beauty of setting up a redirect, you don't really have to painstakingly go through all the documentation to fix url's.

Comment: @Gimby Then there would have been no point in changing *any* link to HTTPS - why not just rely on the auto redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All four of the links in that page have been HTTPS-ified.

Comment: Thank you. This is my 2nd ever [meta-tag:status-completed].